# SSRS and filtering at a field level

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a dataset with a number of records with a unique identifier and a "CreateDate" field.  I need to be able to filter at a field level to determine a count of the number of records added in the last 7 days,  I do not wish to filter at a dataset level.  I have created a "calculated" field to the dataset and I am having difficulty with the syntax to count the records (using the unique field "PropertyId" as my count field) but only counting those records where the create date is within the last 7 days.  The expression I am using for a created field I have named SalesLastWeek is:-

```
=IIf(Fields!CreateDate.Value > =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-7,Today()), =Count(Fields!PropertyId.Value), 0)
```

The error message received is:-

> The expression used for the calculated field
>   '=IIf(Fields!CreateDate.Value > =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-7,Today()),
>   =Count(Fields!PropertyId.Value), 0)' includes an aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function. Aggregate, RowNumber,
>   RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions cannot be used in
>   calculated field expressions.

Comment: Some aspects of your question don't make sense to me, maybe you can help clarify. What is the end product that you are aiming for, a table? Where and how will the count be used? When you say you don't want to filter at the dataset level, do you mean that you don't want to change the query that provides the data for the dataset?

Comment: You shouldn't have the **=** before the **Count**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are trying to do this with an extra field in the dataset. If there's a separate record in your data for each PropertyId (and it seems like there is), you can just make the count by grouping on PropertyId and an expression like:

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!CreateDate.Value >= DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today()), 1, 0))
```

You won't be able to do this in the Calculated field since it uses an aggregate function (SUM). You could make your field work on a record level, but it would be 1 or 0.

```
=IIf(Fields!CreateDate.Value >= DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today()), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Many thanks for yoru considered response.  The dataset has multiple records each with a unique PropertyId and each record contains a date created field and a boolean field to determine if the record is active or not.  There are mulitple offices in the dataset and the report I am trying to produce is grouped by officeId,  showing the total no of active records for each office and also the total number of records added in the last week.  I can then calculate attrition by taking total active records last week (stored in stats table) plus sales this week minus total active records now. copy @Tphe

Comment: @Roscoe01 , Hannover's first suggested formula is what I would recommend using to display the count of records added in the last week. You could easily add in "And Fields!Active.Value = TRUE" to the IIf function's criteria if you need to, or you could filter at the table level. You would want to use this formula in a text box in your tablix at the OfficeID group level.

Answer (score 0):

In Reporting Services, we can't use the aggregation function in calculated field. Because calculated field is also a detail row level data, which means on row level this field should be static. So in the IIF() function, both true part and false part should be a unique static value on row level.